# How to force timer over a process in Matlab

Tags: multithreading, matlab, timer, parallel-processing

I have the classic issue with Matlab and multithreading.

I cannot use MEX because my version of Matlab does not recognize Visual Studio 2013.
I want to try and do it with simple Parallel Computing Toolbox.

MY ISSUE:

I have a GUI and some heavy computations start at a certain point, that blocks everything until is finished.
This computation can last for hours, and i want to be able to pause and check how is going and fine-tune any parameters.
So i have a button with written:PAUSE. but of course this does not do the job because everything is blocked.

i was thinking of making a timer, that halts every 10 secs the processing, lets PAUSE execute if was pressed, else continue.
still this does not work because callback of timer is blocked by processing.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found The solution, and i post it here for anybody who has the same issue.
In the parrallel computin Toolbox you can use jobs...:

```
function Pause_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    %% Now this works. No Need for a Timer.
    %% Timer would work too.
end

function Start_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    myCluster = parcluster;
    MyJob = createJob(myCluster);
    createTask(MyJob,@MyFunction,1,{In});

    submit(MyJob);

    Out = fetchOutputs(MyJob);
end

function Out = MyFunction(In)
    %%% Heavy Computing
end
```

Hope this helps

Comment: How exactly would one use this solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very basic approach to pause a calculation using a hard coded breakpoint:

```
 h=helpdlg('press okay to pause')
 while true
     if ~ishandle(h)
         keyboard;
         h=helpdlg('press okay to pause');
     end
     pause (3)
     disp('simulating')
 end
```

Whenever you close the dialog, `~ishandle(h)` becomes true and the `keyboard` stops the loop.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your reply (i didnt know you could do that) but is not a very clean solution.

Comment: Good to know that you can continue after the break with `dbcont`. You may want to post this answer in the thread I linked to as well.